# Draw upper half of a string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas, graphics

If I have a string, such as `"Hello World!"` How would I draw only the upper half of said string to a javascript canvas?

I would want it to appear like 
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmFyq.png).

Comment: What've you tried thus far?

Comment: 1. `fillRect` the gray background, 2. `fillText` the text, 3. `fillRect` the bottom half of the background (overwriting the bottom half of the text).

Comment: What I'm trying to do, is draw half of one string on the bottom, and the upper half of another string on the top.

Comment: That's not what you said, nor is it what your image illustrates. :-(( Learn about "context.clip".

Comment: I figured this was a less specific way to ask my question.

Comment: "less specific"? You ended up asking half a question! Anyway, learn about `context.clip`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using the .clip() method, you can specify a section of the canvas in which to draw with anything outside the clipping region being omitted; a la:

```
<html>
<body style="background:black;">
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="200"></canvas>
</body>
<script>

    var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
    // Clip a rectangular area
    ctx.rect(50,20,200,80);
    //ctx.stroke();
    ctx.clip();
    // Draw text into clip()
    ctx.fillStyle="#666666";
    ctx.font = "30px Arial";
    ctx.fillText("Hello World",60,110);

</script>
</html>
```

see [this entry](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_clip.asp) for details

good luck!

Comment: This function will be perfect.  Thank you.